# How to use net-snmp 5.5 with IPv6 on Linux?

Tags: linux, snmp, ipv6, net-snmp

Does the Linux SNMP agent support IPv6? I'm working with net-snmp 5.5. It's working fine with IPv4 address set and get operations, but with an IPv6 address it leads to unknown host.

What's the problem, and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 4):

Happened to come across this question while searching for something else and figured I could add my 2 cents.

The IPv6 address in a net-snmp command is a little different from an IPv4 address.  You need to use the udp6: prefix and specify the port number.

```
"udp6:[<ipv6 address here>]:161"
```

The full command should look something like this:

```
snmpset -v 1 -c private "udp6:[<ipv6 address here>]:161" 1.3.6.1.4.1.318.1.1.26.4.4.1.4.1 i 7
```

edit: this works for a Windows environment, but may be the same for Linux

Comment: For Net-SNMP on Linux, you will typically only need to modify /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf to ensure that this line is present:

    agentAddress udp:161,udp6:[::1]:161,tcp:161,tcp6:[::1]:161

That should make snmpd listen on just about everything.

Comment: I added "agentAddress udp:161,udp6:[::1]:161,tcp:161,tcp6:[::1]:161 to snmpd.conf and then launched snmpd. I found no process no for snmpd using 'ps aux | grep snmp'. I then  added only "agentAddress udp:161,udp6:[::1]:161, I found it's lanuched successfuly. But I used 'netstat -uln' command and found only udp  161 was listening, no udp6 161 listening.
How come?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to listening for udp6 packets, it also seems you must specify an additional, separate community for ipv6 requests. Without both changes to snmpd.conf snmp queries via ipv6 are ignored.

```
agentAddress udp:161,udp6:161
rocommunity6 public default
```